# negative values in MudTextField

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Consider this MudTextField that contains a value of type decimal.

```
<MudTextField Value="@Quantity" ValueChanged="(q=> OnValueChanged(q, context))" T="decimal" />
```

Suppose this field contains value 1 and the user wants to input a negative value of lets say -1.

So backspace is pressed and the value becomes '-'. At that point MudTextField errors out with 'not a valid number' and the value changes to '0'. So then another backspace is needed to remove the zero and then add minus sign again.

It's just not user friendly, a bit weird what happens.

Is there a way to have a MudTextField with decimal that is able to have a value of '-'?

Comment: Add an issue to the MudBlazor repo on Github.   They are pretty good on responding.

Comment: hmmm it works on https://try.mudblazor.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are also using `Immediate="true"` (the equivalent of `@bind:event="oninput"`)

> If you use @bind:event="oninput" then you're asking the binding system
> to bind on every keystroke. This inherently supposes that every state
> along the way will be valid and representable in the type you're
> binding to.

The minus '-' character is not a valid decimal number so that's why it becomes 0.

Check this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30033#issuecomment-779170243

Comment: ah yeah, the event triggered immediately so that was it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would look into method `OnValueChanged(q, context)`
There must be some code that handle the validity there...
Or maybe in `@Quantity` itself? How is it defined?

Comment: Quantity  is a decimal so it happens before OnValueChanged

Comment: Tried it on https://try.mudblazor.com/
I can put in negative numbers without problems with this code:

<MudTextField Value="@Quantity" T="decimal" />
@code {
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

That is why I suspected that there is a problem in Quantity, or OnValueChanged definition.